# How add multiple pictures with Facebook Feed Dialog

Tags: facebook, feed

The property 'picture' of the Facebook Feed Dialog object allow only the url of one image.

Add multiple meta og:image does not the trick.

With the deprecated sharer.php, it was possible to choose multiple images defined with the meta og:image.

Is it possible to Add multiple images with the Facebook Feed Dialog object??

Comment: good question, but please show us your codes.

Comment: Yes you can read the code here:
[link](http://www.boodcode.com/trieste/)

and the debugger of facebook
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.boodcode.com%2Ftrieste%2F)

 give me the 4 images but not feed dialog

Comment: From the [Facebook JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), it only supports 1 `picture`. Consider using multiple consecutive calls.